# 'InterfaceContainer' object has no attribute 'WethInterface'

Tags: function, networking, token, program-entry-point, account

from brownie import accounts, config, network, interface

def main():
"""
Runs the get_weth function to get WETH
"""
get_weth()

def get_weth(account=None):
"""
Mints WETH by depositing ETH.
"""
account = (
account if account else accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
)  # add your keystore ID as an argument to this call
weth = interface.WethInterface(
config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
)
tx = weth.deposit({"from": account, "value": 0.1 * 1e18})
print("Received 0.1 WETH")
return tx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue a few days ago. I changed the name of the interface file from "IWeth.sol" to "WethInterface.sol".

I don't know why it worked, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can name the file what you want but, when you want to call the interface you need to call the ***name of the contract*** exactly per example

```
contract WethInterface {}

wethContract = interface.WethInterface(wethAddress)
```